# Website giving 502 error for the past 6 hours

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

[image]

Seeing 502 error for the past 6 hours.

Tried restarting the server but it didn't do anything.

It is hosted on a VM (instead of being an Azure Web App).

Azure region: North Europe.

App Insights resource didn't report of any problem.

Website is written in mvc core.

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you changed anything recently that could be causing this?

Comment: No not at all...

Comment: Have you tried the solutions presented on [Troubleshooting bad gateway errors in Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502)?

Comment: Yes but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already tried the link suggested by DonNetMatt, then, here is what I would do.

- You said you are hosting it in a VM. could you try redeploying the site to another server (web app or VM), and if possible another region. This should tell you if the issue is really with your web app or the server.
- In all likelihood, the redeploy should load the site just fine, in which case contacting Azure support is the best way to solve this issue.

I doubt if the issue is on your code. With the error you are getting, its likely a server issue on Microsoft Azure side.

(Note : I am assuming when you say 'Website is writting in mvc core' you mean, website is written in mvc core. Or, is your website designed to write code as part of some automation thing, and generating MVC code?)

Comment: Thank you mate. Redeploying the site fixed it for me.

Comment: Sorry I meant it's written in mvc core, I was panicked and English isn't my first language. :)